# AJAX CORS error with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, flask

With my Python Flask application, I wanted to do the following from my Javascript.

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:5000/card_clf",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({"line": "가나다라.\tstc"}),
        success: function(res) {
            document.getElementById("div01").innerHTML = res;
        }
    });
</script>
```

However, I got an error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/card_clf. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this by adding "***@app.after_request***" part from the following code to my Python Flask application.

```
from flask import Flask, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/card_clf', methods=["POST"])
def greet():
    ...
    return response


@app.after_request
def add_headers(response):
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type,Authorization')
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#simple-usage) or use the [snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/56/) from flask homepage.
Basic usage of flask-cors is really simple:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/card_clf', methods=["POST"])
def greet():
    ...
    return response
```

It is also highly configurable, as described in documentation.